# .htaccess и русские url

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, url

Привет всем.
Собственно такой вопросик... Как с помощью .htaccess сделать так, чтобы при обращении пользователя по ссылке вида:
http://site.ru/content/мои рисунки/мой альбом 1/рисунок.jpg
этот запрос перенаправлялся например на скрипт http://site.ru/script.php?img=/мои рисунки/мой альбом 1/рисунок.jpg ?
И можно ли это вообще сделать? Очень хотелось бы верить, что можно, потому что иначе мне придется всю мою сделанную работу из-за такого недочета...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /script.php?img=$1 [NS]
```

Вот это работает, но только до первого слэша. Если написать что-нибудь после первого слэша, то вылетает 404 ошибка. А вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ /script.php?img=$1 [NS]
```

Работает для любого количества слэшей, но в скрипт приходит только тот текст, который находится после ПОСЛЕДНЕГО слэша. 
Есть ли какое-нибудь решение моей проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

p.s. Как составить такое регулярное выражение, которое бы применялась бы ко всему написанному после первого слэша в url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы тогда все не переадресовывать?

```
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /somewhere.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Крайне не рекомендую вам использовать русские символы в названиях папок в файловой системы и url - замучаетесь.

Да и при передачи ссылки получится нечто:

`http://site.ru/content/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8/ %D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%201/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83% D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.jpg`

Это я привел всё то, что вы написали, т.е: http://site.ru/content/мои рисунки/мой альбом 1/рисунок.jpg

скажите не очень впечатляюще ?

Кроме всего прочего вроде как  запрещаются такие символы в URI 
в QUERY - пожайлуйста, а вот в URI - нельзя.

Comment: Так вроде я когда перехожу по ссылке: http://site.ru/content/мои рисунки/мой альбом 1/рисунок.jpg у меня нече в этот вид не переводится. Буквы как были русские так и остаются. На википедии же тоже сделано так и нече... живет и процветает... )

Comment: Вопрос пока остается открытым... Если кто знает, то пожалуйста помогите...

Comment: да все работает в википедии и на многих других сайтах