# Почему сервер выдает not found из-за буквы х

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть правило в .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)/(.+?)$ php/page.php?type=$1&theme=$2
```

На сайте страницы открываются по ссылке:

> сайт.ру/page/категория/название

и все хорошо. все страницы открывает как нужно. но проблема с открытием страницы по ссылке:

> сайт.ру/page/категория/хрюша

То есть, если есть русская буква **х** - выдает Not Found

В чем может быть проблема?

.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1251
DirectoryIndex index.php

php_value register_globals 0 
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ready modules/ready.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^2017\/(.+)$ modules/document.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^error modules/error-no-doc.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^not-verified modules/not-verified.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^moderation modules/moderation.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^type\/(.+)$ modules/type.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^all-document\/(.+)/(.+?)$ modules/all-document.php?type=$1&theme=$2
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)/(.+?)$ php/page.php?type=$1&theme=$2
</IfModule>



##ErrorDocument 404 /error`
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68161/discussion-on-question-by-----not-found----).

Comment: будет смешно, если в .httpaccess есть правило отдельное, которое эту букву и матчит:) показывайте весь .httpaccess (и есть ли другие)

Comment: @KoVadim добавил весь код .htaccess . других .htaccess на сайте нет нигде.

Comment: и где же в нем исходное правило:)?

Comment: @KoVadim извиняюсь. убрал его с сервера из-за ошибки. добавил в вопрос.

Comment: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16171/htaccess-и-русские-url)

Comment: @KoVadim вы бы прочитали дискуссию перемещенную в чат, проблема воспросизводится на опенсервер с чистым `htaccess`

Comment: @Денис AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 пробовали?

Comment: а ссылки на русском? Если да то ошибка может быть, потому что символ "Х" на кнопке с "["?

Comment: @GalinaBublik ссылки на любом языке

Answer (score 4):

Уважаемый, я не силен в регулярках, но может вам как то поможет пример с экранированием всех наклонных черт

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)\/(.+?)$ php/page.php?type=$1&theme=$2
```

я про второе `\/`
*все равно. та же ошибка*
Я не силен в .htaccess, но попробуйте использовать флаги

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)\/(.+?)$ php/page.php?type=$1&theme=$2 [L,NC]
```

Это может предотвратить ошибку если у вас *хрюша* например где-то вылезает с большой буквы.

Если это не поможет - переведите формат файла в UTF-8, предварительно сохранив копию оригинала и отпишите о результатах. После каждых изменений перезапускайте сервер(хотя меня здесь могут поправить о необходимости данного шага).

Comment: все равно. та же ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Вопросительный знак во втором выражении стоит не там. Удалите его или вынесите за круглую скобку - вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам нужно что-то ещё после ввода то привнесите варианты для конкретного рассмотрения в своём вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Вопросительный знак лишний и не имеет смысла:

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)/(.+)$ php/page.php?type=$1&theme=$2
```